# Finding energy stored in spherical capacitor

Tags: electromagnetism

What will be energy  stored in a spherical capacitor  with the shells having unequal  charges?

Comment: What have you tried? Please see [our homework policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/715/7433). We expect homework and homework-like problems to have some effort put into them, and deal with conceptual issues. I understand that this may not be a homework question per se, but the same policy applies.

Comment: See capacitance coefficients:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficients_of_potential.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the energy of any system by integrating the energy density of the electric field (and magnetic field, if it exists) over all space. The E-field energy density is given by $u_e=\frac{\epsilon \vert E\vert^2}{2}$.

For the case of a capacitor with equal charges, the fields in many regions go to zero by Gauss' law, and you need to integrate only over the space between the two surfaces. With unequal charges, you get a non-zero electric field outside as well, which needs to be taken into account when calculating energy. Thus, $E_{outside}$ can be found by squaring the field outside and integrating from the outer radius to infinity.